# Print some columns in multiline string

Tags: string, python-3.x, multiple-columns

Is there any way to print some columns in a string which is in several lines. For instance, let's suppose we have the following string:

```
EXAMPLE1
- -- ---
EXAMPLE2
```

And I was only print the columns which has `'-'` in columns. So the the output for this case should be:

```
EAMLE1
------
EAMLE2
```

I was thinking of splitting the string and iterate throug every column by using zip and print just those columns which have `'-'` But don't really know how to use it properly.
Any idea would be welcomed
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we split the string into lines, we can use `zip(*lines)` to transpose the list, getting the columns, search those for `-`, and then transpose again to get the new lines. Then we can use `str.join` to assemble the result.

```
s = '''\
EXAMPLE1
- -- ---
EXAMPLE2'''
columns = (tup for tup in zip(*s.split('\n')) if any('-' in x for x in tup))
lines = (''.join(line) for line in zip(*columns))
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

Output:

```
EAMLE1
------
EAMLE2
```

Comment: Very elegant use of `zip` here.